# Copy One Sheet To Different Workbook...But Paste Values?

Tags: excel, copy, vba

Thanks for all you're help. I've figured it out and have successfully come up with code to carry out what I needed. I have one more question, and hope you'd be able to help. Attached is my code, pay attention to the bold part. I want the sourceSheet to be copied as a sheet and pasted in the targetSheet (the Sheet2 of "NewBook") but I want it pasted as values. Here is the specific part which needs to be looked at...and below is the full code.

```
Set sourceBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(sourceFilename)
Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Sheets("Current")
Set targetSheet = NewBook.Sheets("Sheet2")

sourceSheet.Copy targetSheet
Set targetSheet = NewBook.Sheets("Current")

targetSheet.Name = "Previous"
```

---

```
 Sub Subtype()

Dim sourceBook As Workbook
Dim filter As String
Dim caption As String

Dim sourceFilename As String
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet

If customerFilename = "False" Then
   ' GoTo Here:
End If

filter = "Text files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx"
caption = "Please Select an input file "
sourceFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename

Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
    With NewBook
        .Title = "Subtype Practice"
    End With

Set sourceBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(sourceFilename)
Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Sheets("Current")
Set targetSheet = NewBook.Sheets("Sheet2")

sourceSheet.Copy targetSheet
Set targetSheet = NewBook.Sheets("Current")

targetSheet.Name = "Previous"

sourceBook.Close

Dim sourceBook1 As Workbook
Dim sourceFilename1 As String
Dim sourceSheet1 As Worksheet
Dim targetSheet1 As Worksheet

sourceFilename1 = Application.GetOpenFilename

Set sourceBook1 = Application.Workbooks.Open(sourceFilename1, Password:="BMTBD")
Set sourceSheet1 = sourceBook1.Sheets("Data")
Set targetSheet1 = NewBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

sourceSheet1.Copy targetSheet1
Set targetSheet1 = NewBook.Sheets("Data")

targetSheet1.Name = "Current"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It would be better if you include your current code, even if it desn't quite work.

Comment: got it, just added it @TimWilliams

Answer (score 1):

Your posted code doesn't quite match your description.

Untested:

```
Sub NewPractice()
    Dim wbSrc as workbook, shtSrc as worksheet
    Dim shtDest as worksheet

    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
                 (Title:="Please Choose the RTCM File", _
                  FileFilter:="Excel Binary Worksheet *.xlsb (*.xlsb),")

    If FileToOpen = False Then
        MsgBox "No file specified.", vbExclamation, "Duh!!!"
        Exit Sub
    Else    
        Set shtDest = ActiveSheet    
        Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FileToOpen, PassWord:="passhere")
        Set shtSrc = wbSrc.Sheets("Sheet1")
    End If


    shtDest.Range("A1:Z65536").ClearContents

    lrow = shtSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'EDIT

    shtDest.range("A1:Z" & lrow).Value = _
                     shtSrc.Range("A1:Z" & lrow).Value 

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tim! It works pretty well, except when I try and use it it only copies the first row?

Comment: My bad - it was setting `lrow` from the destination sheet... See edited line.

Comment: Hey, just updated my OP..thanks to you guys I figured it out and have a successful code but I just need help with figuring out how to PasteSpecial Paste:=Values with sheets? (Haven't been able to figure it out)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I'm not 100% what to do about passwords; I'll get back to you.

```
Sub FileImporter() 

Dim sourceBook As Workbook
Dim targetBook As Workbook 'Add this
Dim filter As String
Dim caption As String

Dim sourceFilename As String
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet

If customerFilename = "False" Then
    GoTo Here:
End If

filter = "Text files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx"
caption = "Please Select an input file "
sourceFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

Set sourceBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sourceFilename, _ 
                                            Password:=" ") 'The password goes here
Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Sheets("Current") 

Set targetBook = Workbooks(" ") 'The workbook you're copying TO goes here
Set targetSheet = targetBook.Sheets("Sheet2")

sourceSheet.Copy targetSheet
targetSheet.Name = "Previous"

sourceBook.Close

Here:
End Sub
```

Comment: That looks great as well Al.Sal, but it goes up to and says "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range at this line:::::

Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

Comment: I've also taken into account passwords, @AnilLulla

Comment: Hey, just updated my OP..thanks to you guys I figured it out and have a successful code but I just need help with figuring out how to PasteSpecial Paste:=Values with sheets? (Haven't been able to figure it out

Comment: My pleasure! Don't forgot to choose which answer you thought was the best :)